# JTable loading row by entering the first cell value

Tags: java, swing, jtable, abstracttablemodel

How to load row data by enter the first cell value, for example a watchList JTable and in the first column is the stock code thus when I enter F symbol I will got the detailed info related to the stock like name, last price, bid and Ask?

Comment: See [`TableRowSorter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableRowSorter.html) (which is also a filter).

Comment: the idea is not filtering its about loading rows Individually row by row based on first cell data filling

Comment: *"price, bid"*  Are these values dynamic?  As in, the bid might be changing every other minute (few seconds)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `TableModelListener` to the `TableModel`. An event will be fired when data is changed in the model. If the data is changed in column 0, then you load the rest of the data for the row.